# is there any way to switch ImageJ macro code to python3 code?

Tags: python-3.x, imagej, pyimagej

I'm making an app in python3 and I want to use some function in imagej. I used macro recorder to switch to python code but it got really messy, now I don't know how to do next. Can someone help me, please.

Here is the marco recorder code and my marco code

```
imp = IJ.openImage("D:/data/data_classify/data_train/1/9700TEST.6.tiff40737183_2.jpg");
//IJ.setTool("line");
//IJ.setTool("polyline");
xpoints = [177,155,114,101,100,159,179];
ypoints = [82,94,109,121,133,163,173];
imp.setRoi(new PolygonRoi(xpoints,ypoints,Roi.POLYLINE));
IJ.run(imp, "Straighten...", "title=9700TEST.6.tiff40737183_2-1.jpg line=30");
```

my python3 code

```
mport imagej
from scyjava import jimport
ij = imagej.init('2.5.0', mode='interactive')

print(ij.getVersion())

imp = ij.IJ.openImage("D:/data/data_classify/data_train/1/9700TEST.6.tiff40737183_2.jpg")

xpoints = [177,155,114,101,100,159,179]
xpoints_int = ij.py.to_java(xpoints)
ypoints = [82,94,109,121,133,163,173]
ypoints_int = ij.py.to_java(xpoints)
straightener = jimport('ij.plugin.Straightener')
polyRoi = jimport('ij.gui.PolygonRoi')
```

and I don't know how to do next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I finally found the answer. It is important to understand the parameters of the function to write, I have referenced in:
https://pyimagej.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/module-summary.html
in my example the next thing i need is polygonroi from the given coordinates. I found the required coefficients of PolygonRoi in the above website and determined to take as parameters `PolygonRoi​(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints, int type)`

Next, I found a way to convert my list of coordinates to an `int[]` which was shown in the pyimagej tutorial.
In the type section, I can find it by trying `print(int(roi.PolygonRoi))` and the result is 6, you can also find the reason in the website above in the `Roi` section
The rest, the last thing you need to do is put that `PolygonRoi` into the `Straightener` function with the line value you want
Here is my code for using macro Imagej in Python3

```
import imagej
from scyjava import jimport
from jpype import JArray, JInt

ij = imagej.init('2.5.0', mode='interactive')

print(ij.getVersion())

imp = ij.IJ.openImage("D:/AI lab/joint_detection/data/1/9700TEST.6.tiff133328134_1.jpg")


xpoints = [124,126,131,137,131,128,121,114]
xpoints_int = JArray(JInt)(xpoints)

ypoints = [44,63,105,128,148,172,194,206]
ypoints_int = JArray(JInt)(ypoints)


straightener = jimport('ij.plugin.Straightener')
polyRoi = jimport('ij.gui.PolygonRoi')
roi = jimport('ij.gui.Roi')


new_polyRoi = polyRoi(xpoints_int,ypoints_int,len(xpoints), int(roi.POLYLINE))
imp.setRoi(new_polyRoi)
straightened_img = ij.IJ.run(imp, "Straighten...", "title=9700TEST.6.tiff40737183_2-1.jpg line=30")
ij.IJ.saveAs(straightened_img, 'Jpeg', './test.jpg')
```